# What branch of philosophy or type of morality is this?

Tags: ethics

I've been thinking about morality and ethics on my own, no literature involved (I know very little about philosophy, please be patient), and I came up with a "survivalistic" type of morality - basically, the vast majority of the human population wants to keep on living; humans live in societies and ergo, what is best for humanity is what helps society survive. Regardless of whether that line of thought is correct (although you can correct me in the comments if you wish), could you please tell me the name of this type of morality system or branch of philosophy so that I may learn more? Also, once again, please be patient as I don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: It might be [social ("total") utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_and_total_utilitarianism#Total_utilitarianism) with survival for utility, look also at [evolutionary ethics](http://www.iep.utm.edu/evol-eth)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Conifold](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/9148/conifold) that your claim seems to be social utilitarian. However, you *could* justify the idea that "there ought to be a society" through a variety of means. Thus, it is not the case that there is only *one* specific system that encompasses your view (or parts of your view). For instance, one might consider a variety of [deontological](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/) arguments and [consequentialist](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/) arguments for this view.

With these normative ethical theories in mind, one thing you can do is look at various responses to [the concept of the state of nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_nature).

As an example, Hobbes would say that life in the state of nature is "solitary, poor, nasty, brutish, and short". He gives a set of facts about human nature and then argues that humans should form social contracts to escape the state of nature.

However, if you are only interested in a theory that prioritizes the existence of society "because it is best for humanity" in the sense of a "collective good", then social utilitarianism seems to best describe your view.